# OrElseGet chaining in Java8

Tags: lambda, java-8, option-type

I have a list in which 50 values are coming. Now I have 3 matching conditions, however matching conditions have some order. Like for P1 condition I have to match first, if it does not matches in any element then second condition should be evaluated for logic and so on. How to do this using Java 8 and `orElseGet` chaining.

I was considering to use `orElseGet`, but it requires a supplier.

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: You should show us some code

Comment: I think you could use a comparator evaluating all three predicates and then get the min()

Comment: List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("AB");
        test.add("DC");
        test.add("PQ");
        test.add("EF");
  Now I want to check any AB in test if yes get it, if not check any DC in test (matches get) if not check  EF otherwise a default action ie: get(0) from test.

Comment: @Misha: Sort of, does Or operator will work in above situation???. I was thinking of a solution if we can leverage orElseGet in chain. and for default orElse only.

Comment: @the8472: Thanks for reply. Can you show us in some sample code or example.

Comment: nah, if I did it would have been an answer and not a comment. I merely intended to provide a hint at a possible solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would be to iterate over the conditions first:

```
Stream.<Predicate<String>>of("AB"::equals, "DC"::equals,"XY"::equals)
        .flatMap(condition -> test.stream().filter(condition).limit(1))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(test.get(0));
```

Of course, since in your sample case all conditions are matches to strings, you could do this simpler, but I assume you mean to ask about a general case.

You can also do it with `orElseGet`:

```
test.stream().filter("AB"::equals).findFirst()
        .map(Optional::of).orElseGet(() -> test.stream().filter("DC"::equals).findFirst())
        .map(Optional::of).orElseGet(() -> test.stream().filter("XY"::equals).findFirst())
        .orElse(test.get(0));
```